# Dative/Ablative Substantive Translation?

Tags: translation-check, medieval-latin

Is this translation accurate?

> Qui viam dicit qua ad illam perveniri non tantum potest sed et debet, dicit id quod **optimo et optatissimo** in vita proximum est. Qui hanc viam ignorat, caetera omnia sine fructu discit. Qui hanc novit, is caetera omnia sine periculo ignorat. Omne itaque punctum tulit qui theologiam didicit. Quare non comam oratione, nec lenocinia verborum quaeram, ut ea vobis adlubescat.

The man who says that the way by which this is attained not only can but should say that to the best and most desired in life is the immediate future. He who ignores this way, learns everything else without profit. He who is acquainted with this way, ignores everything else without danger. And thus, he has obtained every point who has become acquainted with theology. Therefore I will not adorn by oration, neither will I seek the allurements of words, in order that these things might be gratifying to you.

Comment: Just a tip: *ignorare* is a false friend: It usually means “not know, be ignorant of” in Latin, where as *ignore* in English usually explicitly means “know but disregard.”

Answer (score 3):

Your last three sentences are accurate, but I believe that the words *optimo* and *optatissimo* should be understood to be in the **dative**, being associated with *proximum* — that is, in the sense of "nearest to the best..."

I would translate the first sentence as:

> He, who designated the way by which it not only can, but even should
>   be attained, says that which is nearest to the best
>   and even the greatest thing in life.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Helped a lot.

Comment: Note that “id, quod … proximum est” cannot very well refer to _via_. I personally would translate this as a relative clause: “… says that which is nearest …”

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel. Thanks! I edited the answer according to your recommendation.